# PrintDocument - Scale or something else not right?

Tags: c#, printing

I'm using a C# printdocument class.  My printer's driver is set to print at 1000 DPI.  I am placing strings down the page at various intervals.  I am using a PageUnit of Pixel (so 1,000 pixels = 1 inch?) to place these DrawString()s down the paper.  Higher in the paper, they appear fine; however as you get lower, they aren't quite as far down as they should be.  By the bottom of the paper, it's off a quarter of an inch.

Any ideas where I should start to resolve this issue?

For example:  the DrawString() that should be Y coordinates 4147 (pixles) down (at 1000 DPI, should be about 4.147 inchs down) is actually only about 4.010 inches down~.

Comment: After further review, I see e.Graphics.DpiX and DpiY are returning 1016 and not 1000.  Why?  Why is there an additional 16 when my driver clearly picks 1000 even?

Comment: Somebody is fumbling a multiplication somewhere, it is not in .NET.  1000 dpi print engines are very unusual.  Look at the price tag, if the printer didn't cost *thousands* of dollar then it isn't actually 1000 dpi.  600 dpi is normal.  Picking a value with such an awkward divisor is unwise, plenty of rounding hazards.  Try 600 or 1200 instead.